# Userform should return only filtered rows

Tags: excel, vba

I use 2 listboxes to filter records but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to return only filtered records. I can see my filtering is working on the spreadsheet. LastRow returns the whole database; the form fills the text boxes from the whole database. If the listbox has a selection, I want only filtered records.

```vb
Private Sub FillTextBoxes()

    'Fill the textbox from the column specified by the Tag property
       
    Dim Ctl As Control
    
    If lstFilter.ListCount > 0 Then
         Me.RowNo = 2
    End If
    For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
       If Ctl.Tag <> "" _
            And Ctl.Tag <> "O" _
            And Ctl.Tag <> "P" _
            And Ctl.Tag <> "Q" Then
        Ctl.Value = Sheet1.Cells(RowNo.Value, Ctl.Tag).Value
        
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: My thought here was that when the spreadsheet is filtered, the filtered rows go to the top and row 2 would be valid. Not so much. Stays on the unfiltered hidden top row.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the visible cells into an array and use the array to populate your controls.

```
Sub test()
    
    Dim vaValues As Variant
    
    vaValues = Sheet1.UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
    
    If True Then 'ctl.tag <> "" etc.
        ctl.Value = vaValues(1, 1)
    End If
    
    
End Sub
```

I'm using the UsedRange less the header, but you probably can define your range more precisely than that. You'll need to either change your tags - arrays don't use column letters - or convert them to a column number. You can do that using the Asc() function.

```
asc("C") - asc("A") + 1
```

returns 3.

Comment: then if they're edited, they would be copied back to the original position?

Comment: No, all this does is fill controls. You'd have to write separate code to write changes back to the worksheet.